# Two statues that appear in the desert are actually aliens that move at glacial pace

Tags: story-identification

More information regarding the story of the discovery of two giant statues in the desert. The main character is called Misha. He is the leader of a team of scientists that go and investigate two statues of a man and a women. In hindsight, I thought the setting of the story was in Russia.

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F.  Is this a short story or a TV show?  What desert do they appear in?  Is it on Earth?

Comment: Not the story you are looking for, but Alan Moore used the same premise in his 1985 short story [*Brief Lives*](https://marswillsendnomore.wordpress.com/2013/01/03/brief-lives-by-kevin-oneill-and-alan-moore/).

Comment: It is indeed called 'Desert Encounter'. Re-reading this short story has jogged my memory. Thank you.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

It is **["Desert Encounter"](https://fantlab-ru.translate.goog/work30828?_x_tr_sl=auto&_x_tr_tl=en&_x_tr_hl=uk&_x_tr_pto=wapp)** by **[I. Rosokhvatsky](https://isfdb.org/cgi-bin/ea.cgi?19884)**,
[isfdb](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?958073)

Other names: "Aliens from another time", "Newcomers from the next hour", "Meeting in time", "Meeting in the desert".

First published in 1961 (ukrainian version).

[image]

**Plot**

> In the middle of the Asian desert, not far from the remains of an
> ancient city, archaeologists have discovered two strange statues of a
> man and a woman. The mystery of the statues haunts researchers.
> According to one of the hypotheses, a spaceship once landed in the
> desert, and intelligent beings left these statues as a sign of their
> stay on Earth. The truth is somewhat different...

**"Misha" character:**

> His name was Mikhail Grigorevich Butyagin. When he came here for the
> first time, **they called him "Misha"**

[Full story (russian)](http://books.rusf.ru/unzip/add-on/xussr_mr/rosoh031.htm?1)

[Full story at archive.org, english version](https://archive.org/details/russiansciencefi0000magi_k3n2/page/n8/mode/1up?view=theater)

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I have been looking fo a long time.

Comment: You're welcome )